# Como remover categorias (levels) não usados na base de dados

Tags: r, data.frame, factors

Suponha que eu tenha a seguinte base de dados:

```
df <- data.frame(categorias=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                 valores=seq(1:5))
```

Quando eu faço um subset desse data frame as categorias que removi continuam.

```
subdf <- subset(df, valores <= 3)
levels(subdf$categorias)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `droplevels`

```
subdf <- droplevels(subset(df, valores <= 3))
```

Resultado:

```
levels(subdf$categorias)
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

A vantagem é que isso funciona para mais de uma variável `factor` ao mesmo tempo. Por exemplo, se o seu `data.frame` fosse:

```
df <- data.frame(categorias=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                 categorias2 = c("F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
                 valores=seq(1:5),
                 valores2=rnorm(5))
```

Se você fizer apenas o `subset` tanto `categorias` quanto `categorias2` iriam ficar com mais `levels`. Com `subdf <- droplevels(subset(df, valores <= 3))` isso é resolvido para todas as colunas de `factor`.